# SSMS expand databases very slow with over 8000 databases

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Our SQL Server has over 8000 databases.

To expand the database-node in my SSMS (2012 and 2014, both) takes around 2 minutes, sometimes longer (when there is a lot of traffic).

Is there any way to reduce this time?

I read somewhere, don't know where, that the problem is, that for every database the SSMS asks if you have rights to see them, open them, expand them (or something like this).

Comment: If you want to connect to specific database, you can call `sqlcmd` utility with `/d` switch. Please, read this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180770%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I'd recommend to detach unused databases.

Comment: This might be helpful too: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176037%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thx guys... 1) I cant specify the database before using the expand view... sorry... 2) I cant detach anything because every database is used!

Comment: You could familiarise yourself with the [catalog views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx) so that you no longer need the object explorer? e.g. -- `USE Database; SELECT * FROM sys.tables;`, or for a column list -- `SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.tableName', 'U')`

Comment: Thx Gareth, nice idea but in fact its not about me, its about 20 other developers too...

Comment: Used to have a similar problem, but with stored procedures node, not the databases. Learned never to expand the SPs node, but use the object explorer details window instead..

Answer (score 1):

You would need to revoke the permission 'VIEW ANY DATABASE' from the role PUBLIC (SQL SERVER 2005 onwards) and give permission to the users only for the databases they need. This should make Object Explorer faster.

Comment: This would help for some cases, in fact our development team need access to all databases here, so the question isn't how to reduce the count of shown databases - the question is how to make it fast to see 8000+ databases in this view? (As I told allready there seems some confusion about the perimission checks)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Sql Server 2014. It took me about 1 minute to expand the databases tree with only 10-15 databases listed.

The solution to me was to run the Sql Server 2014 setup and **repair** the installation. Even though nothing seems to be incorrectly installed this still fixed the issue for expanding the databases tree.

Answer (score 0):

Rene,
Have you tried using the latest preview version of SSMS ([available here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx))? I believe the issue might have also been addressed in the SSMS 2014 Service Pack 1 release ([you can find that here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff803383.aspx))

Comment: Thx very much, I will try this!